# How to force JavaFX ComboBox to loose focus?

Tags: java, combobox, javafx-8

I would like that my JavaFX `ComboBox` looses the focus after a selection. Any ideas?

Comment: AFAIK you just have to request focus on another component.

Comment: had to dummy-edit to remove my downvote :-)

Comment: @kleopatra, what it prompts when you upvote your previous downvote again?

Comment: @UlukBiy hmm... not sure I understand: to revert a (up/down) vote I have to click on the up/down triangle again: no prompt, it's just removed. Once a vote is locked (usual grace period of 5 min) I can do so only after the post is edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, javafx has no public api to programmatically transfer focus *away* from a node. A workaround - as suggested by [James_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189127/james-d) - is to explicitly request the focus onto another node:

```
node.requestFocus();
```

Doing so implies that the calling code knows that node (which seems to be the case in OP's context).

Actually, there *is* api on Scene that provides the needed functionality. The down-side: it's package private and requires usage of the class Direction in the com.sun.xx hierarchy. So if you are willing (and allowed) to take the risk an alternative is to reflectively invoke that api:

```
/**
 * Utility method to transfer focus from the given node into the
 * direction. Implemented to reflectively (!) invoke Scene's
 * package-private method traverse. 
 * 
 * @param node
 * @param next
 */
public static void traverse(Node node, Direction dir) {
    Scene scene = node.getScene();
    if (scene == null) return;
    try {
        Method method = Scene.class.getDeclaredMethod("traverse", 
                Node.class, Direction.class);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(scene, node, dir);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException 
            | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException 
            | InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// usage, f.i. on change of selection of a comboBox 
combo.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((source, ov, nv) -> {
    traverse(combo, Direction.NEXT);
});
```